# Scrolling the panel in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, windows

I'm on windows using After Effects CS6.

I'm new to this software and am having a problem scrolling the window vertically or horizontally, **Where is the scroll bar?**

Alternatively I'm trying to scroll using the mouse wheel, but this seems to be zooming in and out. I read that I can hold the Alt or Ctrl button while moving the wheel, but that doesn't make any difference.

I just want to scroll the panel up and down so I can see what I'm doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After tearing my hair out I found the "hand cursor", now I can drag the panel around however I want it :)

[image: After Effects Hand Cursor]

Comment: Glad you found it.  Thanks for posting what you found.  Also, welcome to AVP.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Also - try holding the space bar down.. It temporarily turns your cursor into a hand grabber.  Very "handy" (sorry)